# How to check if a bound method is the same as unbound

Tags: python, class

I want to check (in my tests) that a method of object is the same as a method of a given class.

```
class Cls:
    def foo(self):
        pass

obj = Cls()
assert obj.foo == Cls.foo  # assert will fail
```

Which operation can be used instead of `obj.foo == Cls.foo` to produce `True` if the bound method is the same as unbound (except for 'boundness')?

Comment: What about `id(Cls.foo) == id(obj.foo)  #returns true ` ?

Comment: While this is a **good question** (because potential answers will teach us valuable insights about the language), **asserting this in your tests might often be a bad idea** and a sign that you're testing the implementation's innards rather than its behavior. (Depends on the specific context of course. If you're testing your own ORM that makes use of reflection, a test like this can make sense.)

Comment: It is a test for argument parsing  in my app (with subparsers), and I want to be sure that `args.command` is 'the' command for given subparser (each subparser is a separate class). Snippet from my actual test code: `assert args.command.__func__ == commands.TransferCommand.command.__func__`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Python 2.7.x :

```
>>> Cls.foo.__func__ is obj.foo.__func__
True
```

Answer (score 4):

In Python 3:

```
>>> class Cls:
...     def foo(self):
...         pass
... 
>>> obj = Cls()
>>> obj.foo
<bound method Cls.foo of <__main__.Cls object at 0x101d8f588>>
>>> dir(obj.foo)
['__call__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__func__', '__ge__', '__get__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__self__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__']
>>> obj.foo.__func__
<function Cls.foo at 0x101d92400>
>>> obj.foo.__func__ is Cls.foo
True
```

Looking through the `dir()` of an object is an easy way to explore and look for potentially useful attributes.

Comment: Doesn't work on Python 2.7.x  - `Cls.foo` is un unbound method, not the `Cls.__dict__["foo"]` object.

Answer (score 2):

Combining [bruno desthuilliers's solution for Python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41162427/674064) and [Alex Hall's solution for Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41162233/674064) to one that works on both versions:

```
class Cls:
    def foo(self):
        pass

obj = Cls()
assert getattr(Cls.foo, '__func__', Cls.foo) is obj.foo.__func__
```